# Sum for same ID in every row SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I am having table as below..

```
    r_Id     Marks
     1        25
     1        25   
     1        25
     2        30
     2        30
```

now i want a query in which sum of marks for each r_id should be calculated and result should be

```
    r_Id  MARKS   Sum
     1      25    75   
     1      25    75
     1      25    75
     2      30    60 
     2      30    60
```

I need to do this in oracle without using PL/SQL. Please Help.
I have tried using CUBE, ROLLUP, GROUPING SETS in GROUP BY, but nothing is working.

Comment: Could you please post the query/queries you *did* try, and the results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the analytic functions for this.  These are the functions that use an `over` clause:

```
select r_id, Marks, sum(Marks) over (partition by r_id)
from t;
```

Comment: If the OP is unfamiliar with analytic functions: These links might be useful: http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select table1.*, sums.mark_sum
from table1
inner join (
  select r_id, sum(marks) mark_sum
  from table1
  group by r_id ) sums
on  sums.r_id = table1.r_id
```

On SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a935/2

Answer (score 0):

```
select r_id,s.marks,t.p from table s
left join
(select r_id,sum(marks)p from table
group by r_id)t
on s.r_id=t.r_id
order by t.p asc;
```

Hope this left join query answers your question.